# Sorting 2 arrays - one of chars and one of integers

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, tree, trie

so I have two arrays, one with some n number of chars (could be around 1000-2000) and second with exact same number n of integers. Chars represent words, and integers numbers of occurences of these words in my tree. I want to sort it so the word with highest number of occurences is first, second highest second etc etc. Could anyone lend me a hand, please? I have not taken data structures/algorithm class yet so I am having problems with that.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])
#define ALPHABET_SIZE (26)
// Converts key current character into index
// use only 'a' through 'z' and lower case
#define CHAR_TO_INDEX(C) ((int)C - (int)'A')
#define INDEX_TO_CHAR(IX) ('A' + IX)


char words[3000][40]={{0}};
int counters[3000]={0};
int wordnr=0;

typedef struct trie_node trie_node_t;
struct trie_node
{
    int counter;
    trie_node_t *children[ALPHABET_SIZE];
};

typedef struct trie trie_t;
struct trie
{
    trie_node_t *root;
    int count;
};

// Returns new trie node
trie_node_t *getNode(void)
{
    trie_node_t *pNode = NULL;

    pNode = (trie_node_t *)malloc(sizeof(trie_node_t));

    if( pNode )
    {
        int i;

        pNode->counter = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++)
        {
            pNode->children[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    return pNode;
}

// Initializes trie
void initialize(trie_t *pTrie)
{
    pTrie->root = getNode();
    pTrie->count = 0;
}

void setorder_rec(trie_node_t *pCrawl, char *str, int n)
{
    if (pCrawl == NULL) return;

    if (pCrawl->counter) {
    str[n]='\0';
        strcpy(words[wordnr],str);
        words[wordnr][strlen(str)]='\0';
        counters[wordnr]=pCrawl->counter;
        wordnr++;
        printf("%.*s: %d\n", n, str, pCrawl->counter);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++) {
        str[n] = INDEX_TO_CHAR(i);
        setorder_rec(pCrawl->children[i], str, n + 1);
    }
}

void setorder(trie_t *pTrie)
{
    char tempword[40] = {0};

    setorder_rec(pTrie->root, tempword, 0);
}

void insert(trie_t *pTrie, char key[])
{
    int level;
    int length = strlen(key);
    int index;
    trie_node_t *pCrawl;


    pTrie->count++;
    pCrawl = pTrie->root;

    for( level = 0; level < length; level++ )
    {
        index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(key[level]);
        if( !pCrawl->children[index] )
        {
            pCrawl->children[index] = getNode();
        }
        pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index];
    }

    pCrawl->counter++;

    printf("counter slow 3= %d\n", pCrawl->counter);
}


int main()
{
    char keys[][20] = {"THE", "THE", "BYE", "A", "THERE", "ANSWER", "ANSWER", "BBUWNTSMFK", "THE", "THEIR", "ANSWER", "THE", "LOL", "OMG", "WTF"};
    trie_t trie;

    char output[][20] = {"Not present in trie", "Present in trie"};

    initialize(&trie);

    // Construct trie
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(keys); i++)
    {
        insert(&trie, keys[i]);
    }

    setorder(&trie);

    for(int i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        printf("#%d %s=%d\n", i, words[i], counters[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Arrays that I want to sort are "words" and "counters"

Comment: Do you want to sort words[] based on counters[]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple bubble sort code you can use:

```
for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
  {
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
    {
      if (counters[d] > counters[d+1]) 
      {
        swap       = counters[d];
        counters[d]   = counters[d+1];
        counters[d+1] = swap;
        swap2       = words[d];
        words[d]   = words[d+1];
        words[d+1] = swap2;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Sorted words:\n");

  for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
     printf("%d\n", words[c]);**strong text**
```

Comment: Thanks, so I put this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c64317b4213cc9694fa0 but the thing is, it's uhm, upside down - highest value is at the last place. What should I do to fix that?

Comment: You can change the comparison sign in "counters[d] > counters[d+1]" :-)